# Jquery focus on append element

Tags: jquery

I want to focus an element with Jquery created by an append.
My exemple :

```
$("#Collaps").append('<a id="link_tuiles_1" href="test.php">Link</a>')

$("#link_tuiles_1").focus(function(){       
alert('ok');   
});
```

---

```
<div id="Collaps"></div>
```

But it doesn't works. 
Could you help me ?

Comment: $("#Collaps").append('<a id="link_tuiles_1" href="test.php" > Link </a>') .focus();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not work because you bind the function before the element is inserted on page, try it like this

```
("#Collaps").append('<a id="link_tuiles_1" href="test.php">Link</a>')

$(document).on("focus","#link_tuiles_1",function(){       
 alert('ok');   
});
```

Comment: That's my problem, you solve it ! But I don't understand why the previous jsfiddle works too ?

Comment: Also if you want to bind event to dynamically added elements, elements that are added to the DOM after you load the page, this is the way to bind events to the elements